# How would you delete a specific row without using panda in Python 3.4.4?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, python-3.4

I've tried to find ways to delete a selected row but the only way I could do so is with panda.

What I want to do is to delete an entire row that matches with the csv library (errors are fine since I'll make code if the row doesn't exist) as I had developed the code around said library, I've been told that 'wb' works around deleting rows, but I'm only able to delete 2 cells instead (which doesn't even work)

```
with open('StudentDetails.csv', 'wb',) as csvfile:
      csvFileWriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
      a = delete_student_entry.get()
      b = delete_password_entry.get()
      csvFileWriter.writerow([a,b])
```

Comment: you can read line by line from original file and check which line write to new file - and later rename new file to old name.

Comment: It's probably not relevant but can you upgrade your Python version? 3.4 hasn't been supported for a while.

Comment: mode `w` delete all from file - and you have to write again all rows which you need to keep - but first you would have to read all rows to memory

Comment: @AlexHall I should do that tbh, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @furas That's actually a really good idea... If I didn't need the file, it's part of a login system. :(

Comment: you have two methods. First: read all from file to memory, delete in memory, write all from memory to the same file. Sedocn: read line by line from original file, save in new file only lines which you need, delete original file and rename new file to 'StudentDetails.csv'

Answer (score 0):

You could do this the old fashioned way (if you want to avoid using pandas) -

```
with open("StudentDetails.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("StudentDetails.csv", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != "YOUR ROW HERE":
            f.write(line)
```

This will overwrite the file while deleting the row you want to avoid.

If you really want to use the `csv` library you can do the following -

```
import csv

with open('StudentDetails.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     output = [x for x in csvreader if x != [YOUR LINE HERE AS A STRING]]

with open('StudentDetails.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for x in output:
        csvreader.writerow(x)
```